# Pass variable to Javascript and calling

Tags: javascript, php, youtube-javascript-api

I have a code with Javascript to play Youtube videos instead of iframe but I don't know how. Do I pass the video id from a PHP script variable or a bbcode like `[youtube]videoid[/youtube]`?
I just need to pass down the video code to this function. So please help me and maybe this may have discussed here but I could not find it (maybe I don't know what exactly I have to search for).
Here is the code:

```
<script>

  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE', // remove if assign in php
      events: {


      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Or assign videoId: in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
videoId: <?php echo json_encode($videoId); ?>,
```

JSON-encoding is compatible with JavaScript and will take care of any escaping and what not that may need to be done.

Comment: Why the downvotes?  It's a real erosion of quality around here when a perfectly good answer is downvoted.  If you don't think it's a good answer, add a comment as to why so it can be improved.  Or, answer the question yourself.

Answer (score -1):

How about directly outputting the variable?

```
videoId: <?php echo json_encode($vIdVariable); ?>,
```

Comment: Your quotes break this.